# Assign names to ranges from one workbook to other

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub XXXX_Click()

Dim rng As Range
Dim rng2 As Range

Dim SummaryWb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim tba As Variant
Dim wss As Variant
Dim tbrange As Variant
Dim myRangeName As String


wss = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ORSA").Range("G2:G10")
tbrange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ORSA").Range("J2:J10")
tba = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ORSA").Range("C2:C10")


Set SummaryWb = Workbooks.Open("xxxxxx.xlsx")

For i = 1 To UBound(tba)

Set ws = SummaryWb.Worksheets(wss(i, 1))
Set rng2 = SummaryWb.ws.Range(tbrange(i, 1))

myRangeName = tba(i, 1)

SummaryWb.Names.Add Name:=myRangeName, RefersTo:=rng2

Next i
```

Hello, this is my code. I try to assign names to ranges. I have two workbooks. The workbook1 has the range names, the ranges to assign the name and the worksheets names in the SummaryWb (which is the second workbook). This is an example:

1) wss is a variant variable which stores the names of the worksheets, f.e. Sheet1a

2) tbrange is a variant variable which stores the ranges i want to assign the names, fe "A12:B25"
----> Please note that the ranges are in SummaryWb

3) tba is a variant variable which stores the names of the ranges I wont to assign, fe RangeName1

My code doesn't work. I don't know why. I get errors when i try to set rng2 and the name doesn't change in the second workbook.

What can I do?

Comment: Start by explaining exactly what errors and on which lines they occur. Please include that in your question.

Comment: Set rng2 = SummaryWb.ws.Range(tbrange(i, 1)) here i get this error: Run-time error '438: Object doesn't support this property or method. And then it doesn't change the name to the range

Comment: `ws` is already defined as a worksheet object. You dont need to also include the workbook object with it, as it is implied. So remove this: `SummaryWb.` - What is the next problem?

Comment: This was my problem. Thank you. Is there any links with the syntax of VBA? I am sorry, but i am new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ws` is already defined as a worksheet object by this line in your code.

```
Set ws = SummaryWb.Worksheets(wss(i, 1))
```

Once you have that set, you do not need to include the workbook reference anymore, as it has already been set. With that said, update the next line to this:

```
Set rng2 = ws.Range(tbrange(i, 1))
```

As for other references to VBA coding, there are plenty of options available.

[Here is one example](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/index.htm)

Look up specific examples based on what you are trying to do on google and include `StackOverflow` in the search box for the best results.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this code will do what you intend. Please try it.

```
Private Sub XXXX_Click()

    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim WsNames As Variant
    Dim RngAddresses As Variant
    Dim Nnames As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myRangeName As String
    Dim Target As String

'    Set Wb = Workbooks.Open("xxxxxx.xlsx")

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ORSA")
        Nnames = .Range("C2:C10").Value
        WsNames = .Range("G2:G10").Value
        RngAddresses = .Range("J2:J10").Value
    End With

    For i = 1 To UBound(Nnames)
        myRangeName = Trim(Nnames(i, 1))
        Target = "'" & WsNames(i, 1) & "'!" & Range(RngAddresses(i, 1)).Address

        On Error Resume Next
        Wb.Names.Add Name:=myRangeName, RefersTo:=Target
        If Err Then
            MsgBox "Name: " & myRangeName & vbCr & _
                   "RefersTo: " & Target & vbCr & _
                   "Error: " & Err.Number & _
                   Err.Description
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```